# Python: compose list from nested iterators

Tags: python, functional-programming, iterator, scope, function-composition

I have a list of tuples that I need to expand it by adding two elements, each of them comes from a list. So I have `[(1, 2, 3)]` and two iterators `it1 = (i for i in ['a1', 'a2'])` and `it2 = (i for i in in ['b1', 'b2'])`. The result should be `[(1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b2'), (1, 2, 3, 'a2', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a2', 'b2')]`.

If I use iterators as show above it doesn't work. But if I use lists it works. Here is the code:

```
def get_iters():
    return ((i for i in ['a1', 'a2']), (i for i in ['b1', 'b2']))

def get_lists():
    return ([i for i in ['a1', 'a2']], [i for i in ['b1', 'b2']])

def compose(lst_of_tuples, iter=True):
    iters = get_iters() if iter else get_lists()
    for it in iters:
        lst_of_tuples = [t + (i,) for t in lst_of_tuples for i in it]
    return lst_of_tuples

print compose([(1,2,3)], True)
# WRONG!???? (what happened to the 'a2' part of it?)
# prints: [(1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b2')]

print compose([(1,2,3)], False)
# RIGHT!! prints: [(1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b2'), (1, 2, 3, 'a2', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a2', 'b2')]
```

I can't think of a reason why that would be. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterables can only be iterated over *once*, after which they are exhausted.

When looping over a given iterable a second time in a for loop, no more elements are returned.

Loop over `itertools.product()` first instead, then over your list of tuples to generate ouput:

```
from itertools import product

def compose(lst_of_tuples, iter=True):
    iters = get_iters() if iter else get_lists()
    return [t + i for i in product(*get_iters()) for t in lst_of_tuples]
```

This produces:

```
>>> print compose([(1,2,3)], True)
[(1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b2'), (1, 2, 3, 'a2', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a2', 'b2')]
>>> print compose([(1,2,3)], False)
[(1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a1', 'b2'), (1, 2, 3, 'a2', 'b1'), (1, 2, 3, 'a2', 'b2')]
```

Comment: OK. I understood now. The iterators (it1 or it2) runs out after the first element of `lst_of_tuples` is iterated over. So the code only really worked for the first element. If I do `[t + (i,) for i in it for t in lst_of_tuples` it then works. Thanks for the itertool.product idea - neat.